# multienum package within enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol

Is it possible to use the multienum package within the enumerate environment? The following code does not display correctly (the last column moves to the next line):

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxx{Not1}{Linear1}{Not1}
\mitemxxx{Not2}{Linear2}{Not2} 
\end{multienumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Also, if this is possible, how could I change the numbering? Since multienumerate is nested within the enumerate environment, I would like to have each item tagged with alph characters (a,b,c...). If this is not possible, could someone please suggest an alternative approach.

Ideally, what I would like to create is the following:
1. Question 1 Preamble
   (a) part a          (b) part b      (c) part c
   (d) part d          (e) part e      (f) part f
2. Question 2 Preamble
   (a) part a          (b) part b      (c) part c
   (d) part d          (e) part e      (f) part f

where parts a-c and d-f span the linewidth and the labels are vertically aligned.

Comment: Perhaps the shortlst or multicol package could be good alternatives. Thoughts?

Comment: The problem with the shortlst package is that the horizontal and vertical spacing does not look good. The problem with the multicols package is that the numbering is vertical instead of horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `\hsize` to `\linewidth` inside `multienumerate`, so the environment is aware of the current value for the line width (the package uses `\textwidth` by default); the representation for the counter used can be changed ny redefining `\labelenumi`. Another option, if your inner items are naturally balanced would be to use three columns built, for example with the `multicol` package. The following example shows both alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multienum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\noindent Using \texttt{multienum}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\setlength\hsize{\linewidth}
\begin{multienumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{0}
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}
  {\addtocounter{enumi}{1}\alph{enumi}.}
\mitemxxx{Not}{Linear}{Not}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent Using \texttt{multicol}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Not 
\item Linear
\item Not
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps the best option is to use the `enumerate*` environment from the `enumitem` package with the `inline` package option and to control the spacing between items using `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent With \texttt{enumitem}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hfill]
\item Not
\item Linear
\item Not
\end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the edit to the original question, a better option seems to be the use of a `tabularx` environment (from the `tabularx` package) of width equal to `\linewidth` and with automatic cell numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{row}
\renewcommand\therow{\alph{row}}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{*{3}{>{\stepcounter{row}\makebox[1.8em][l]{(\therow)\hfill}}X}}
part 1 & part 2 & part 3\\
part 4 & part 5 & part 6\\
\end{tabularx}
\item
\setcounter{row}{0}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{*{3}{>{\stepcounter{row}\makebox[1.8em][l]{(\therow)\hfill}}X}}
part 1 & part 2 & part 3\\
part 4 & part 5 & part 6\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, if this structure is to be used several times, you can define a new environment to simplify the writting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{row}
\renewcommand\therow{\alph{row}}

\newenvironment{rowenum}
  {\setcounter{row}{0}%
    \par\noindent\tabularx{\linewidth}[t]
    {*{3}{>{\stepcounter{row}\makebox[1.8em][l]{(\therow)\hfill}}X}}%
  }
  {\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Question 1 preamble
\begin{rowenum}
part 1 & part 2 & part 3 \\
part 4 & part 5 & part 6 \\
\end{rowenum}
\item Question 2 preamble
\begin{rowenum}
part 1 & part 2 & part 3 \\
part 4 & part 5 & part 6 \\
\end{rowenum}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If there is more than one row, multicols numbers vertically. How can I change it so that it numbers horizontally?

Comment: If I use multienumerate, how can I change the labels to alph characters? Also, is there a way to make the \hsize property change global to avoid having to add that line every time I call the environment?

Comment: @richtera please see my updated answer; the last option (the one using only `enumitem`) is the best option.

Comment: In the last example, if you add a second row, the labels do not line up.

Comment: @richtera please state your full requirements clearly in your question. In your question, as it is now, you only require three in-line items; now, apparently you need something different.

Comment: @richtera please see the code of my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to horizontally number using multicol?

Comment: @richtera no, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @richtera I updated my answer with a simplified version using a newly defined environment.

Comment: Great. What does the X at the end of the part in braces do?

Comment: @richtera `X` is the main column format specifier offered by the `tabularx` package. It is equivalent to a `p{<length>}` column, once the appropriate length has been internally calculated.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the distance between the rows?

Comment: @richtera well, of course. You can, for example, say `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}` (use an appropriate value) right after `\setcounter{row}{0}` in the definition of the `rowenum` environment (this will affect all the rows), or you can use `\\[1em]` (use the appropriate value) inside the tabular body for individual rows.

Comment: I should be more specific. With the multicol environment, the vertical distance between the rows naturally adjusts depending on the contents of each "cell". Using the tabularx package, of course it no longer automatically does this. Is it possible to create a naturual buffer between the rows depending on the cell contents using your method?

Comment: @richtera sorry, but I don't understand; perhaps you should open a new question as a follow-up to this one?